# Get all products and categories (and sub/sub/sub..) to treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have table constructed like that:
[image]

Now i'd like to add all of categories, subCategories, subsubCategories etc to my treeview, but dont really know how to construct sql query. Any suggesions?
Example with that table i posted on pic:

```
- ZupyEDIT
- Lody
- Mięso
  - Mięso wieprzowe
  - oi
- RTV
  - Edit
    - Laptopy
    - Komputery stacjonarne
    - Pamięć przenośna
    - Modemy
- GSM modemy
```

Answer (score 0):

As all your data comes from the same place (not from different structures) you're lucky :o). It's more or less like this:

I will assume you have that data in some sort of hierarchical structure, which I'll name 'MyRootCategories', which starts as a list of the root items. Also assume each item has a collection of children, which I'll name 'MyChildren'.

Create an HierarchicalDataTemplate, as a resource, like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hdt01" ItemsSource="{Binding MyChildren}" >
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding name1}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Feed your TreeView's ItemsSource with the list 'MyRootCategories'. Also set your TreeView's ItemTemplate property to point to the 'hdt01' template. And that's all.

Comment: Hmm, still dont get it. How can i acces (and even add) this HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: All that is not a control, or usercontrol, have to be putted in a Resource collection, or, you can directly set your TreeView's ItemTemplate property to the given HierarchicalDataTemplate.